# Errno 121 on restoring mysqldump to empty DB

Tags: mariadb

One of our MariaDB users decided to copy a database via a shell script that pipes the output of a mysqldump to another table.

If you restore the mysqldump to a database that hasn't been created before, it works just fine. However, if you then drop that database, re-create it, and then try to run the script again, it throws the following error:

> ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 25: Can't create table
>   `core_dev`.`addresses` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")
>   mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS yields the following insight:

> 2017-05-03 09:34:19 7f9929fb4b00 Error in foreign key constraint
>   creation for table `core_dev`.`addresses`. A foreign key constraint of
>   name `core_dev`.`addresses_ibfk_2` already exists. (Note that
>   internally InnoDB adds 'databasename' in front of the user-defined
>   constraint name.) Note that InnoDB's FOREIGN KEY system tables store
>   constraint names as case-insensitive, with the MySQL standard
>   latin1_swedish_ci collation. If you create tables or databases whose
>   names differ only in the character case, then collisions in constraint
>   names can occur. Workaround: name your constraints explicitly with
>   unique names.

However, the core_dev database is entirely empty:

> MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW TABLES IN core_dev; 
>   Empty set (0.01 sec)

What could the problem be? I'm not able to replicate this problem on any of our other MariaDB 10.1 servers. The only difference is that this particular one is running on CentOS 6, while the others are on CentOS 7.

Comment: Let's see the `SHOW DATABASE...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`.  It might be a `COLLATION` issue.

Comment: From the description of the behavior, it sounds like there are some abandoned records in the InnoDB dictionary. (This is conjecture, based on the error message, which makes it appear that InnoDB is checking for a foreign key constraint, and is "finding" one, even though we know it shouldn't exist. I'd check the version point release MariaDB (10.1.X) and InnoDB, and compare that to the environments where you aren't able to replicate this problem.) This behavior might be the result of InnoDB dictionary corruption.

Comment: @RickJames I'm afraid most of this troubleshooting is new to me; my experience with MariaDB is limited. Can you clarify which commands I should run? It looks like the CentOS 6 server is running MariaDB 10.1.22, and the others are on 10.1.23. Identical InnoDB versions.

Comment: Learn how to use MySQL Workbench or phpmyadmin or the mysql commandline tool.

Comment: @RickJames https://pastebin.com/VJKRF626

Comment: Hmmm... Nothing seems wrong in the `CREATE TABLE` for that table.  When you say "drop that database, re-create it", to you really mean "database", or just "table"?  Let's see the first chunk of the dump file (before it gets into the first insert).

Comment: @RickJames Yes, I'm dropping the entire core_dev database. I then re-create a "core_dev" database and then attempt to restore the mysqldump to it. Here's the chunk you requested: https://pastebin.com/pzMcL9WG

Comment: `utf8` is mentioned twice in the dump file; is that the same for all situations?  Does the text look correct?  When "looking", by what means are you viewing the text?  (Often clients try to 'fix' encoding problems, thereby clouding the problem.  If possible "look" at its hex.)